µ = $N(0,\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2))$ is an equilibrium distribution for $K(x, ·) = N(\alpha x,\sigma^2)$
$\mathit S$ = $\mathbb R$, $K(x, ·) = N(\alpha x,\sigma^2)$ with |$\alpha$|<1.
Then µ = $N(0,\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2))$ is an equilibrium distribution for $K$.$$-$$ I understand the definition of equilibrium distribution: µ = µK where µ = $\mathbb P \circ X^-1$ and $K(·, ·)$ is a transition probability. So my approach was to use the formula for normal distribution, and I directly multiplied $\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\sigma^2\sqrt{2\pi}}$e^$-\frac{(1-\alpha^2)^2(x)^2}{2\sigma^4}$ by $\frac{1}{\sigma^2\sqrt{2\pi}}$e^$-\frac{(x-\alpha x)^2}{2\sigma^4}$ but it was not equal to $\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\sigma^2\sqrt{2\pi}}$e^$-\frac{(1-\alpha^2)^2(x)^2}{2\sigma^2}$. My guess is to use Central Limit Property, but I was not able to find a way to proceed from this point. I would gladly accept any advice or a hint for this problem. Thank you.

The main idea is that an equilibrium distribution when acted upon by the transition kernel Remnant unchanged. inch price of chance concentration Roles (pdfs) that way the pdf of the balance dispersion $p(y)$ have be the intrinsic of $p(x)k(xy)$ across complete contingent $x$ where $k(xy)$ is the pdf of the kernel
the pdf of $n(0\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ is $p(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1-\alpha^2}{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(1-\alpha^2)x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$. The pdf of the transition kernel $N(\alpha x \sigma^2)$ is given by $k(xy) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y-\alpha x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$.
as an result the equilibrium condition becomes the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) k(x y) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2\pi \sigma^2}  \exp\left(-\frac{(1-\alpha^2)x^2}{2\sigma^2} - \frac{(y-\alpha x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx$$
Combining the exponents under the integral this leads to:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2\pi \sigma^2}  \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left[ x^2 - 2\alpha y x + y^2 \right]\right)dx$$
Completing the square in the exponent with respect to $x$ and reorganizing terms yields:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2\pi \sigma^2} \exp\left(-\frac{(1-\alpha^2) y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \exp\left(-\frac{ (x - \alpha y)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)dx$$
The integral part is the integral of a Gaussian pdf (with mean $\alpha y$ and variance $\sigma^2$) which evaluates to $\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$. the integral look simplifies to:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(1-\alpha^2) y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
this consequent look is congruent to the pdf of $n(0\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ which way we've proven the balance condition: $p(y) = \int p(x)k(xy)dx$. Hence $N(0\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ is indeed the equilibrium distribution for the given kernel. the principal head was recognizing that the intrinsic subsequently complementary the straight was amp gaussian pdf and hence organic to one (when right normalized)

I truely appriciate your detailed and knowledgeable answer. Now I understood clearly, and I'll study what was lack in my study of probability theory. Thank you very much once more.

Rule: If $Y\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$ always write $Y=m+\sigma Z$ with $Z\sim N(0,1).$   Here you are asked to show that if $X\sim \alpha X+ \sigma Z$ with $X$ independent of $Z$ then the law of $X$ equal to $N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ is a possible solution. Well we know that if $Z_1,Z_2$ are two independent $N(0,1)$ rv then $$a_1Z_1+a_2Z_2\sim N(0,a_1^2+a_2^2)\ \ (*)$$ and this leads immediately to the result.
But this leads  to the problem, is $N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ the only solution?  The answer is yes, and we proceed as follow to see it. Without loss of generality we take $\sigma=1.$ Let  a distribution $\mu$ of $X$ such that if $X$ is independent of $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then $\alpha X+Z$ has distribution $\mu.$ Consider now an infinite sequence $Z_n$  iid rv with distribution $N(0,1)$ and $X_0\sim \mu$ independent of all  $Z_n$. Then
$X_{n+1}=\alpha X_n+Z_n\sim \mu$  for all $n\geq 0$  Furthermore
$$ X_{n+1}=\alpha^nX_0+\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^k Z_{n-k}\sim \alpha^nX_0+\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^k Z_{k}$$ Since $\alpha^nX_0\to_{n\to \infty} 0$ one can say that $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha^k Z_{k}\sim \mu.$$ But applying (*)
$$S\sim N(0, \sum _{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{2k})=N(0, \frac{1}{1-\alpha^2})$$ as desired.
